# How to find start and end index of DOM text selection?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textselection

In jQuery Terminal I want to add an API that will return indices of the selection.

Example HTML I have:

```html
<div class="cmd" style="width: 100%; --cursor-line:1; top: 0px;">
    <div class="cmd-wrapper" style="">
        <span class="cmd-prompt" style="visibility: visible; margin-left: 0px;">
            <span data-text=">&nbsp;">
                <span style="width: 2ch;">&gt;&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <div role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" class="cmd-end-line">
            <span data-text="H">
                <span>H</span>
            </span>
            <span data-text="e">
                <span>e</span>
            </span>
            <span data-text="l">
                <span>l</span>
            </span>
            <span data-text="l">
                <span>l</span>
            </span>
            <span data-text="o">
                <span>o</span>
            </span>
            <span data-text="&nbsp;">
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
            <span data-text="W">
                <span>W</span>
            </span>
            <span data-text="o">
                <span>o</span>
            </span>
            <span data-text="r">
                <span>r</span>
            </span>
            <span data-text="l">
                <span>l</span>
            </span>
            <span data-text="d">
                <span>d</span>
            </span>
            <span data-text="&nbsp;">
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="cmd-cursor-line" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true">
            <span>
                <span data-text="x">
                    <span>x</span>
                </span>
                <span data-text="x">
                    <span>x</span>
                </span>
                <span data-text="x">
                    <span>x</span>
                </span>
                <span data-text="x">
                    <span>x</span>
                </span>
                <span data-text="x">
                    <span>x</span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="cmd-cursor" style="">
                <span data-text="" class="end">
                    <span>&nbsp;<span></span></span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <textarea autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="1" class="cmd-clipboard" data-cmd-prompt=">&nbsp;" style=""></textarea>
</div>
```

This is copy-paste of the DOM after entering "Hello World\nxxxxx" and formatted and pretty printed using https://jsonformatter.org/html-pretty-print

My question is what should I do to get the selection indices?

For example, I have a command like this:

```
> He|lo wor|d
```

I should get `[2, 8]` and if the selection is outside of the range: example

```
>|>> Hello| world
```

where `>>>` is prompt I should get `[0, 5]` I don't care about the negative. I should also handle when the whole selection is outside

```
|>>>| Hello World
```

it should return `[0, 0]` or null.

How would to implement something like this? Note: that I only care about [window.getSelection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) it's 100% support, not need to be silly and support
IE8.

Comment: I don't understand: Isn't window.getSelection (with it's start and end api) the answer?

Comment: @ControlAltDel Where do you have start and end API in the selection, I don't see it on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

Answer (score 0):

You want something like

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var start = range.startOffset;
var end = range.endOffset;
```

Note that this code assumes that range.startContainer === range.endContainer (which it often does). If you want to get the text / the length of the text between the start and the end containers, you need to recursively traverse the DOM between them. There is also an issue where the length of the text in the DOM is not the same as the length of the text in HTML (browsers sometimes add spaces and other HTML elements)

You'd be right if you guessed that I've worked a bunch in Javascript with selections. IMO it's kind of a nightmare. Tim Down has written a very popular package called `Rangy` which I recommend it a lot. You should check it out and see if it meets the requirements of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue myself:

```js
 var selection = window.getSelection();
 var start = $(selection.anchorNode);
 var end = $(selection.focusNode);

 var before = start.closest('.cmd [role="presentation"]').prevUntil('.cmd-prompt');
 var count = 0;
 if (before.length > 1) {
     count = before.find('[data-text]').length;
 }
 var s = start.closest('.cmd [role="presentation"] [data-text]');
 var e = end.closest('.cmd [role="presentation"] [data-text]');

 if ((s.length || e.length)) {
     start = count + s.index();
     end = count + e.index() + 1;
     console.log({start, end});
 }
```